# Installing Indy - which folders should be added to Delphi's Library list?

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe4, indy10

The directions on how to install Indy10 are (at least to me) a little vague in one place, and I'm hoping someone here can clarify a little.

The installation directions (From http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.en.aspx) state:

> After Compiling
>
> **In your Indy directory** you should now see some compiled .dcu files.
>   Open the IDE and go to the "Tools > Environment options > Select
>   Library" dialog tab. Now add **the path to your files** into the filepath
>   collection. Click Ok.

My Indy10 folder does not have any `.dcu` files in the root folder. It does have a bunch of DCU files in `C:\code\Indy10\Output\DCU\Win32\Debug` ... does this mean I should be adding `C:\code\Indy10\Output\DCU\Win32\Debug` to my library path? (And for that matter, should I be building Indy in *Debug* or *Release* mode, or does it matter?) Are there any other subfolders I need to add to the library path? Indy 10 has a much more complex folder structure than Indy 9 and I'm not convinced I've configured things "correctly".

Comment: If you want to use already compiled dcu, ensure the dcu folder comes first. Usually, although many packages don't because of laziness, dcu should go into a separate directory, preferably named after the Delphi version building it (especially if you use more than one version). Then you may need the source folders, because they can contain some .dfm or .res used when compiling (unless their copied to the dcu folder). Debug dcu should go to a separate folder as well, to support their use when the option is selected. Remember you may want to recompile after a Delphi update is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly every component package I install I touch the project options for the *runtime package(s)* to get a clean install.

- Project Options

  - General Configuration

    - Output directory `{componentpath}\lib\XE4\$(platform)\$(config)`
  - Release Configuration

    - Output directory `{componentpath}\lib\XE4\$(platform)`

After that I compile the whole package for all target platforms in *release* and *debug* mode. Using a Build-Group is very useful to do that.

Now it is time to add the library paths (for each platform)

- Library path `{componentpath}\lib\XE4\$(platform)`
- Debug DCU path `{componentpath}\lib\XE4\$(platform)\debug`
- Browse path *all directories containing the source*

In your own projects you can control which `.dcu` versions are used by setting the `Use Debug-DCU` option.